# Remove text from a widget from another website

Tags: javascript, css, text

I want to remove the text marked in the image.

[image]

It is a widget from another website.

Can you with javascript insert a  around the text, and then remove it with css? I would like to keep the strong element inside the span.

```
<p class="Firmafon-external-css-widget-call-status Firmafon-status-available">
<span class="Firmafon-call-status-4571995996">Sidste opkald blev besvaret på <strong class="Firmafon-call-status-answer-time-4571995996">26 sekunder</strong></span>
```

Comment: copied the code..

Comment: Can you not just target those classes in your css - if the control is appearing on your site (and not in an iframe) your css should be applied to it

Comment: First of all, I kind of have to point out that overwriting code from a different source is tricky, and depending on JS in this aspect is probably your only choice if there is an Iframe in play. If you are running jQuery. do something like `$(.Firmafon-status-available span).hide();` but no garantuee if it will work due to there is very limited code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to remove only the text *"Sidste opkald blev besvaret på"*, but save the `<strong>...</strong>` inside the parent `<span>`? So:

UPD: a solution with CSS:

```
.Firmafon-external-css-widget-call-status.Firmafon-status-available span {
  font-size: 0;
}
.Firmafon-external-css-widget-call-status.Firmafon-status-available span strong {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

A solution with JavaScript:

1. Store the `<strong>` element;
2. Clear the `<span>` element;
3. Insert the stored `<strong>` into the cleared `<span>`.

Below an example:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', removeText);

function removeText() {
  var p = document.querySelector(".Firmafon-external-css-widget-call-status.Firmafon-status-available");
  if (!p) return;
  var span = p.querySelector("span");
  var strong = span.querySelector("strong");
  span.innerHTML = '';
  span.appendChild(strong);
}
```

Comment: Tried the above, but doesn't seem to work.
On this page: https://realkreditkonsulenten.dk/12118-2/ code: test

Comment: You should add this script in the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: Still not working - could it be a conflict with another script?

Comment: I can't see that elements in your page... If the content is generated dynamically, you should call this script only after the content has been generated.

Comment: I did - it's in the bottom of the page (as far down as it can be (wordpress)

Comment: I changed the script - now it waits for load and checks if the element exists.

Comment: A bit weird - tried to add "" around strong in the last line - it removes something. actually everything. Then it worked out of the blue, then not.. hmm - of course removed the "" again..

Comment: You can't write `span.appendChild("strong")`, because `"strong"` is a string, not an element.

Comment: I know - was just testing. It's removed, but still not working.

Comment: It just worked, but then I updated and then it didn't - why can that be? That it only works sometimes?

Comment: The problem is the content is loading slower than the script. But I have found another solution :)

Comment: Yay - you're an angel! :-)

Comment: DOH - why haven't i thought of that - i tried a lot of other css, but not this.. haha! Thanks :D perfect!

Comment: Maybe nobody thought about CSS because of the screenshot from Developer tools, that forced to think about JS :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are able to access/modify these DOM elements:

```
var queryP = ".Firmafon-external-css-widget-call-status.Firmafon-status-available",
    keepHTML = document.querySelector(queryP + " strong").innerHTML;
document.querySelector(queryP).innerHTML = keepHTML;
```

Basically, this will store the HTML code inside that paragraph's strong element and remove the rest.

Comment: I am - I can edit everything with css anyway. 
Tried the above, but doesn't seem to work.
On this page: https://realkreditkonsulenten.dk/12118-2/ code: test